# Combining Values of an Array into FormArray Rows in Reactive Forms

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-reactive-forms

I'm trying to submit a product and i need to get also the `this.totals[].amount and this.totals[].total.` Right now, i can only get the `this.myForm.get('rows').value`. I need to insert in the rows the this.totals[].amount and this.totals[].total. How can i do this? Here's the link to my code

[CLICK LINK HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h2wdfz?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

```
onCreateProduct(){
   const formData = {
     products: this.myForm.get('rows').value
   }
   console.log(formData)

  }

patchValues() {
    let rows = this.myForm.get('rows') as FormArray;
    this.orders.forEach(material => {
      material.materials.forEach(x => {
        rows.push(this.fb.group({
          material_id: x.id,
          material_name: x.name,
          quantity: [null, Validators.required],
          price: [null, Validators.required],
          dis_checkbox: [true],
          checkbox: [1.12]
        })) //see that total and amount is NOT in the form
        this.totals.push({amount:0,total:0});  //<--add this line
      })
    })
    this.setOnChange();
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily add data to your rows on submit in your `onCreateProduct` function. Change the code to the following:

```
const formData = {
  products: this.myForm.get('rows').value.map((row, i) => {
    row.amount = this.totals[i].amount;
    row.total = this.totals[i].total;
    return row;
  })
}
```

Comment: The other values for each product are still there. We're just adding the `this.totals` information onto the existing product information. You could replace the variable `row` with the variable `product` if that would make more sense.